# Session Variables and protected page errors

Tags: php, sql, session, cookies

I currently have a login form that redirects the user to another page if the login is successful. The page is supposed to be a protected page that will not open for the user if they are not logged in and will redirect them to the login form page.

In order to do this I stored the login data (email & password) as session variables and used these to verify if the user is allowed to view the page.

In my login php page I have the following code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($count == 1) {
      $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
      $_SESSION['email'] = $myemail;
      $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
      header("Location: account.html");
      exit();
    }
?>
```

And I begin my account html file with the following :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['logged'] != 1) { //no session
        header("Location:memberlogin.html");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

However any time I load the account page I am allowed to view it each time. Its my first time using the Session variableand Im not sure if i Used it correctly.

**FIXED Thanks to suggestions below**

I tweaked the code suggested below and my protected page is now working. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Don't store the password in the session. You should never need it.

Comment: I don't see `session_start()` anyhwere

Comment: The php code cannot be referenced from an html page. Change `account.html` to `account.php` before anything else.

Comment: @JohnConde session_start() beig left out was a copy paste error . I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

The php code won't be referenced from an html page.
So, change account.html to account.php then add the session check code on top of the page as follows:

account.php:

```
  <?php
  if ($_SESSION ['logged'] !=1) { 
  //User is not logged in
  header ("Location:memberlogin.html");
  exit();
  }
  ?>
```

However, redirecting is not the best solution, you can display an error message if user is not logged in, else grant user access to the page information.
You can implement it as follows:

account.php:

```
 <?php

  if ($_SESSION ['logged'] !=1) { 
  //User is not logged in, display an error message
  echo 'You need to be logged in to access this page';
  exit();
  }
   else{
   //Display all information that only a logged in user can view
   echo 'You are logged in, you can view the page';
       }

 ?>
```

Comment: Forgetting something? Hint: `session_start()`

Comment: @mutiemule Thanks for your advice. I tweaked the code you suggested and my page is now working.